# Set orientation to landscape in android on both sides

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am working in an android application in 2.2 and I want to set my application in `landscape` mode.

For that I added in my `manifest` with every activity tag   `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` and it worked fine.

But it comes only in one side. If I turn the device again upside down it fit in the same position in `landscape` mode. How can I have landscape mode in both the side of the device. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
```

Comment: In android 2.2 I am not getting a property named reverseLandscape in android:screenOrientation in the activity tag. In which version are you getting this property.

Comment: Oh, sorry, this property since API Level 9 (for android 2.3)

Comment: There is no other way to do that

Answer (score 0):

To get an Android application to display in landscape mode only, add this line to your Activity definition in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

For example, this is the definition for my main activity in the Android manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this, I think it will help you

```
addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, onOrientationChange);

function onOrientationChange(event:StageOrientationEvent):void {
     trace("onOrientationChange:"+event.afterOrientation);
    ...and process result.
    }
}
```